# Redirect http->https, but exclude subdomain

Tags: https, htaccess

I use Drupal, with a complicated multi-Domain setup, and have a local development site, that uses (locally) the dev. subdomain.
So I want a .htaccess file that can be used on production AND development.

The production site is used with HTTPS, and there is a HTTP->HTTPS redirect in the htaccess file.
I just want to NOT redirect to https if on the .dev subdomain:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteBase /

  # use website without "www."
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^ http%{ENV:protossl}://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

  # force HTTPS, but don't if on local development site
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
  RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !=on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^dev\.(.+)$ [NC]
  RewriteRule .* https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

But this does not work, and creates a loop redirect. But I can't see why. Any hints?

Comment: Is there a good reason you are doing this in `.htaccess` instead of the main apache configuration for your site?

Comment: Yes. Good reason is Shared Hosting. No access to global apache config.

Comment: But yes, the .dev part could at least be done in the local development VM in the global apache site.conf. But what exactly?